# Rails: forcing SSL causes loss of traffic source in Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have switched my Rails application to HTTPS with config.force_ssl = true. Everything works fine, except I am seeing a spike of *direct traffic* in Google Analytics. After inspecting and testing I am sure it is caused by ssl redirects. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is your `<script src=` for Google analytics? What gem are you using for it and look at the final src on the production page.

Comment: <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-86428967-4"></script>. I am not using any gems, just copy/pasted google's snippet.